# Prove that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are strictly increasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> The sequences of real numbers $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ satisfy $a_{n+1} = (a_{n-1}-1)(b_n+1)$ and $b_{n+1}=a_nb_{n-1} - 1$ for $n\ge 2$ with $a_1 = a_2 = 2015$ and $b_1=b_2=2013.$ Prove that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are (weakly) increasing.

I tried to prove this using induction, but I can't seem to resolve the issue. Below shows my incomplete attempt at trying to come up with an inductive hypothesis and at trying to justify why the unboundedness of the sequences assuming they're both increasing.

We have $a_3 = (a_1-1)(b_2+1) = 2014^2 > a_2, b_3 = 2015\cdot 2013 - 1 = 2014^2 - 2 > b_2, a_4 = (2014)(2014^2-2),b_4 = 2014^2\cdot 2013 - 1 > a_3.$

Inductive hypothesis (some parts may not be true): $a_{k+1} \ge a_k, b_{k+1} \ge b_k, b_{k+1}\ge a_{k}, a_{k+1}\ge b_{k+1}, b_k > 2, a_k > 2, a_{k+1}\leq a_{k}^2-1$ for all $2\leq k < n, b_k$ some $n\ge 3.$ Observe that $b_n = a_{n-1}b_{n-2} - 1 > 2, a_n = (a_{n-2}-1)(b_{n-1}+1) > 1\cdot 3 >2.$ Then $a_{n+1} = (a_{n-1} - 1)(b_n+1) \ge a_{n-1}^2-1\ge a_n$ and $b_{n+1} = a_nb_{n-1} -1 \ge b_n b_{n-1} - 1 \ge b_n + 2b_n-1 > b_n$ from the inductive hypothesis. $b_{n+1} \ge 3a_n - 1 > a_n + 2a_{n-1}-1 > a_n.$ $a_{n+1} = (a_{n-1}-1)(b_n+1) = a_{n-1}b_n - b_n+a_{n-1} - 1, b_n$.

If we assume for a contradiction that $a_n$ is bounded, then since it's increasing, we can find real numbers $M$ and $L>1$ so that $L\leq a_n\leq M$ for all n and then $b_n = \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n-1}-1} - 1 \leq \dfrac{M}{L-1} - 1,$ so $b_n$ is bounded above. Similarly, if $b_n$ is bounded above, then we can find real numbers $L>1,M\ge L$ so that $L\leq b_n\leq M$ for all n and then $a_n = (b_{n+1}+1)/b_{n-1} \leq (M+1)/L $ so $a_n$ is bounded above.

Comment: Note: If you can show an positive integer sequence is strictly increasing, it is bounded below by $n$ and therefore goes to infinity.

Comment: Can you explain why you are "trying to justify why the unboundedness of the sequences assuming they're both increasing."? That's not a requirement of a (weakly) increasing sequence.