# Find the expected value of $|H-T|$

Tags: calculus, probability, summation, contest-math, expected-value

> Bob repeatedly throws a (fair) coin. For each throw, there is a $4\%$ chance that Bob decides to stop throwing the coin. He records the number of heads H and the number of tails T before he stops flipping the coin (if he decides to stop flipping the coin on a toss, he doesn't record anything for that toss). Find the expected value of $|H-T|$.

Let $p=1/25$.

I'm not sure whether the expected value of $|H-T|$ after n+1 throws given that it is nonzero after n throws equals the expected value after n throws. Note that the probability that $H-T < 0$ after n flips and the (n+1)st throw is an H equals the probability that $H-T > 0$ and the (n+1)st throw is a T (we can simply replace H's with T's in the corresponding sequences). Also, the probability $H-T < 0$ and the (n+1)st throw is a T equals the probability that $H-T>0$ and the (n+1)st throw is an H. Also, the probability $H-T < 0$ after n throws and the (n+1)st throw is an H equals the probability $H-T<0$ after n throws and the (n+1)st throw is a T. Let $I$ be an indicator random variable equal to $-1$ if $H-T < 0$ and the (n+1)st throw is an H or $H-T > 0$ and the (n+1)st throw is a T and $1$ if $H-T > 0$ and the (n+1)st throw is a T or $H-T < 0$ and the $(n+1)$st throw is an H. I'm not sure about how to proceed from here.

Alternatively, I think it should be possible to find the expected value of $|H-T|$ assuming $n$ tosses were performed directly from the definition, and then compute the desired expected value using the fact that the probability n successful flips were performed (not including the last flip) is $p(1-p)^n$. Now if i is nonzero, then the probability that $|H-T| = i$ equals the probability $H-T = i$ plus the probability $H-T = -i$. In the first case, since $H+T = n, H = \dfrac{n+i}2, T = \dfrac{n-i}2$ while in the second case, $H = \dfrac{n-i}2, T = \dfrac{n+i}2.$ And clearly the probability $|H-T| = 0$ is ${n\choose n/2}$ assuming n is even; if not the probability is zero. So the expected value of $|H-T|$ is just $1/2^n \sum_{i=1}^n 2 {n\choose \dfrac{n+i}2} i,$ where ${n\choose k} := 0$ if $n$ is an integer but k is not. In particular, if $n$ is odd, then the expected value is $\dfrac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=0}^{(n-1)/2} 2{n\choose \dfrac{n+2i+1}2} (2i+1)$ while if n is even, the expected value is $\dfrac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} 2{n\choose \dfrac{n+2i}2}(2i).$

> **Question:** how can I simplify the latter expression or come up with the expected value using a different method?

By computing a few small values, it seems that the last expression actually equals $\prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor } \dfrac{2i+1}{2i}$. Let us call the latter assumption assumption (*). I'm not sure how to prove this, so I'll just assume this is true from now on.

We have
\begin{align} E(|H-T|) &= p\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p)^n \prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor } (2k+1)/(2k))\\
&= p(\sum_{m=0}^\infty (1-p)^{2m+1} \prod_{k=1}^m \dfrac{2k+1}{2k} + \sum_{m=0}^\infty (1-p)^{2m+2} \prod_{k=1}^m \dfrac{2k+1}{2k})
\\
&= p(1-p)(2-p) \sum_{m=0}^\infty (1-p)^{2m} \prod_{k=1}^m \dfrac{2k+1}{2k} \\
&= p(1-p)(2-p) (1-(1-p)^2)^{-3/2}\\
&= (1-p)/\sqrt{p(2-p)},
\end{align}

and so plugging in $p=1/25$ gives that the expected value is $24/7$ under assumption (*).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not simplifying OP's expression. Here is an alternative approach to showing that $$E_{n} |H-T| = \prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor } \dfrac{2i+1}{2i}.$$

We'd prove this by induction.
Let $A_n$ denote the act of throwing $n$ coins. We say that $ a_n = k$ if $|H-T| = k$.
Let $ E_n$ denote the expected value of $|H-T|$ when throwing $n$ coins.

For $A_n$, first consider the cases where $ |H - T | =k > 0$.
Restricting to these cases, when we flip an additional coin, the expected value stays the same, namely
$$E_{n+1} ( |H-T| \mid a_n = k ) = \frac{1}{2} (k+1) + \frac{1}{2} (k-1 ) = k = E_n ( a_n = k).$$

Let's first focus on an odd number of coin flips, and what happens when we add an additional coin flip.
$|H-T| $ is odd, so by Linearity of Iterated Expectation,
$$ E_{2n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} P(a_{2n-1} = 2k-1) \times E_{2n-1} (|H-T| \mid a_{2n-1} = 2k-1 ) \\
= \sum P(a_{2n-1} = 2k-1) E_{2n-1} ( a_{2n-1} = 2k-1 )   \\= E_{2n-1}.$$
Notice that $E_{2n} = E_{2n-1}$ is reflected in the closed form.

Now we focus on the $n=2k$ even number of coin flips, and what happens when we add an additional coin flip.
$|H-T|$ is even. We understand what happens when $|H-T| \geq 2$, so let's investigate when $|H-T| = 0$.
This occurs with probability $P(a_{2k} = 0 ) = \frac{2k \choose k } { 2^{2k}}$.
With the next coin flip, we have $|H-T| = 1$ always, so $E_{2k+1} ( |H-T| \mid a_{2k} = 0 ) = E_{2k} ( |H-T| \mid a_{2k} = 0 ) + 1$.
Thus, by Linearity of Iterated Expectation,

$$ E_{2n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} P(a_{2n} = 2k) \times E_{2n+1} (|H-T| \mid A_{2n} = k )\\
 = P(a_{2n}  =0) +  \sum_{k=0}^n P(a_{2n} = k) E_{2n} ( a_{2n}= k )   \\ = \frac{2k \choose k } { 2^{2k}} + E_{2n}.$$

By induction (check the math), $E_n$ has the closed form as given above.

Comment: Why does the answer have nothing to do with the $4\%$ condition?

Comment: @youthdoo Read OP's writeup again, in particular the "**Question**: how can I simplify ...",There are 2 parts to the originally worded block. The first part is calculating $E_n$, which they have trouble determining. $\quad$ The second part, which comes in after the "**Question**", calculates $ E = \sum P(n) \times E_n$ and uses the $ p = 4\%$. OP has done that completely, and isn't asking for clarification, hence I do not need to use it. $\quad$ Note that I'm assuming the coin is fair (which OP assumed in their writeup, but didn't explicitly state).

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks. Could you take a look at [this likely simple sequences problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616360/prove-that-a-n-and-b-n-are-strictly-increasing) if you have time?

Comment: Also, I can't seem to understand the recurrence you got. I did the following, but I'm not sure if I made a mistake somewhere: $E_{n+1} = P(a_n = 0 ) \times E_{n+1} (|H-T| \mid a_n = 0 ) + P(a_n > 0) \times E_{n+1}(|H-T| \mid a_n > 0) = P(a_n = 0)\times E_{n+1}(|H-T|\mid a_n = 0) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty k P(|H-T| = k \cap a_n > 0) = E_{n+1} (|H-T| \mid a_n=0) P(a_n = 0) + P(|H-T| = 1 \cap a_n = 2) + \sum_{k=2}^\infty k (P(|H-T| = k \cap (a_n = k+1)) + P(|H-T| = k \cap (a_n = k-1)))$.

Comment: Also, when I "did the math" as you suggested at the end, it seems the explicit formula is only true if $E_{2k+2} = E_{2k} + {2k\choose k}/2^{2k}.$

Comment: @user33096 Yes, sorry I was in the midst of fixing various errors from the original draft, but then had to leave. This is now fixed, and should reflect your 2 concerns (which end up cancelling each other).